# Ctrl X Replaces Text with Cancel Character CAN Notepad++

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++

So I just realized this on a Laptop I recently started using.

When I try a simple cut and paste in notepad++ it doesn't work. When I select a given text and press `Ctrl`+`X`, it simple replaces the text with the cancel character `CAN` without even copying the highlighted text to clipboard. A subsequent `Ctrl`+`V` doesn't paste anything at all because nothing has been cut.

Is there some configuration I need to do somewhere (Perhaps in Windows or Notepad++)?

Comment: In Notepad++, The command for cutting is `Ctrl` + `L` and for pasting is `Ctrl` + `D`. However, I Don't know how do you make it the usual shortcut, and that's why this is just a comment

Comment: And I'm Doubtful if there exists any direct way to configure it, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619754/how-to-mimic-visual-studios-ctrl-x-ctrl-v-functionality-in-notepad) for reference

Comment: No repro with my notepad++

Answer (score 1):

@saaranshgarg Thanks for the tip. It turns out the keyboard command for cut in my version of notepad++ was `Shift`+`Del`. I changed it to `Ctrl`+`X` and all is settled now.